# Saving data to a variable from Firebase without using a completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Instead of my code looking like

```
var relID: String = " "
var userID: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userID = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!

    Helper.helper.getRelID(userID) {
        (result: String) in
        let relID = result
    }

    print("after completion handler"+relID) // prints "after completion handler "
}
```

Helper

```
func getRelID (userID: String, completionHandler: (result: String) -> Void) {
    var relID: String = "nil"
    ref.child("users").child(userID).child("Rel").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.value != nil {
            print("rel id " + (snapshot.value as! String))
            relID = snapshot.value as! String
        }
        else {
            print ("rel not found")
            relID = "nil"
        }
        completionHandler(result: relID)
    })
}
```

I was wondering if I could just call a function in `viewDidLoad()` that would save `relID` so I could use it after the completion handler ended.

`relID = Helper.helper.getRelID(userID)`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you just remove that `let` in `let relID = result`?